# How do you encrypt a .mp3 audio file?

Tags: audio, encryption

I've recorded an interview as an .mp3 file and would like to send this file to someone over email.  Because the contents of the interview needs to remain confidential, I need to find some way to encrypt it.

I tried zipping an audio file with the 7-zip program, and encrypting the zipped package, but when I tested this by sending the audio file to two friends (along with the password), one person got the message "an error occurred" and another got the message "unable to open this file."

I found this [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fh8203k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), which seems promising, but it is way too technical for me.  Does anyone know of a simple way to encrypt audio files?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: oops, sorry.  I'm really stuck

Comment: By the way, it's not secure to send the password along with the encrypted file. This is just obfuscation. You would either need to meet with the recipients face to face or use asymmetric crypto.

Comment: As far as I understand, you are not going to code the app. There are both commercial and non-commercial encryption software some of which are listed here: http://lifehacker.com/five-best-file-encryption-tools-5677725

Comment: Thanks for the list @mcy

Answer (score 0):

7-zip can encrypt a file *while* compressing, not *after*.  Just add a password while you're making the .7z file.  (Note that mp3 files won't compress much, if at all.  You're just using 7-zip for its encryption).

You could also use PGP, if the person you're sending the file to has given you (or registered) a public key.  PGP is a higher level of security than most zip programs.

Comment: thanks @gcal, you made my day.  Maybe Artjom B. will see your question and comes up with a recommendation for another site.  As for your suggestion, I confirm I added a password to the 7-zip file (I used the password to open it when it is on my computer). But something weird happens when I send the 7-zip file over the internet and the file becomes unusable.  Right now, I'm exploring using proton.mail.  Thank you for your time and suggestion.

Comment: @oymonk You don't seem to have a specific question or specific requirements which is why your question is not a good fit for any site on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Okay, but I've tried different encryption software on the .mp3 files and I still can't get them opened by my recipient over email.  So, it seems like maybe audio files can't be encrypted?  in which case, the answer to this question is something only a programmer would know.

Comment: @oymonk No, modern ciphers work on arbitrary binary data. They don't care whether it's an mp3 file or not. Symmetric encryption software like 7zip or asymmetric software like GPG is portable and would work for any file. I see four very different causes: 1. there are transmission errors 2. there are character set issues when typing in the password 3. you're sending DRM protected files without moving the license data 4. the receiver makes typos when entering the password 5. you make errors when giving the receiver the password. Either way this is not a programming question

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you so much for helping me even though I'm breaking the stackoverflow rules.  Your information gives me hope that what I'm trying to do is possible :-)

Comment: It turns out that the peeps on the other end were trying to open the file directly from their email, rather than saving the file to their PC, and opening it once saved.  Peazip worked the best.